# How to use angular translate directive with limitTo filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular translate directive in my application. Now i am translating a key which returns a string.

```
<div translate="TRANSLATION_KEY"></div>
```

suppose I got the translation in string form as `apply online for this course`.

Now i want this string to limit to only 12 characters like this`apply online...`.

so i have done like this

```
<div {{translate="TRANSLATION_KEY | limitTo:12 }}"></div>
```

but this is not correct
so
how can i use `limitTo` filter when expression is coming from translation itself.

Also what is the use of `translate-values` and `translate-compile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Limiting string with `limitTo` filter**

> {{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

```
{{ "My String Is Too Long" | limitTo: 9 }}
```

Which will output:

```
My String
```

Or use following approach (not using the `translate` directive.

```
<span>{{TRANSLATION_KEY|translate|limitTo:9}}</span>
```

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/04_using-translate-filter

**About the other question regarding the `angular-translate` directive.**

> The translate directive expects an optional `translate-values`
>   attribute you can use to pass some values through it. All you have to
>   do is to combine the directive with the translate-values attribute.
>
> You can pass either an object literal as string, expression, or, if
>   the value is dynamic, an interpolation directive. Whatever you pass
>   in, it gets internally evaluated and parsed by translate filter, so
>   what comes out is a plain old JavaScript object which gets passed to
>   $translate service.

```
<ANY translate="TRANSLATION_ID"
     translate-values='{ username: "PascalPrect"}'></ANY>
```

or

```
<ANY translate="TRANSLATION_ID"
     translate-values="{ username: someScopeObject.username }"></ANY>
```

or

```
<ANY translate="TRANSLATION_ID"
     translate-values="{{translationData}}"></ANY>
```

**Post compiling**

> Starting with version 2, the translation itself can be post processed
>   in context of the current scope (using `$compile`). This means any
>   directive used in a translation value itself will now work as
>   expected.

This behavior can be enabled per directive:

```
<ANY translate="TRANSLATION_ID" translate-compile></ANY>
```

In addition to it, you can also enable the feature globally with...

```
$translateProvider.usePostCompiling(true);
```

... and even then you can disable the feature again per directive:

```
<ANY translate="TRANSLATION_ID" translate-compile="false"></ANY>
```

Comment: I want to use filter when expression is coming from translation itself. I have edited my post, please have a look at it.

Comment: See my answer using `<span>{{TRANSLATION_KEY|translate|limitTo:9}}</span>`. See more at https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/04_using-translate-filter

Comment: Thanks @daan.desmedt that's what i was looking for.